# Short-hand syntax for fetching multiple keys from secret map in kubernetes yaml config

Tags: yaml, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-secrets

In my kubernetes deployment config, I want to fetch two environment variables from a secret map called "my-environment-config". Currently the way I do that is as follows:

```
    env:
      - name: INFLUXDB_DATA_ENGINE
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: my-environment-config
            key: INFLUXDB_DATA_ENGINE
      - name: INFLUXDB_DATA_QUERY_LOG_ENABLED
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: my-environment-config
            key: INFLUXDB_DATA_QUERY_LOG_ENABLED
```

This syntax seems to me to be overly verbose. Is there no shorthand for specifying this more elegantly?

PS: It is important to note that I don't want to expose ALL the secrets of my-environment-config, just a select few.

Comment: This syntax is exactly the same like in the documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables. There's no other ways as I can see. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: Becuase it is really too verbose. 5 lines per environment variable is a lot!